# Use Google Sheets for resource allocation

Tags: google-sheets, project-management

I am trying to figure out how to use Google Sheets to allocate resources to tasks automatically based on multiple variables (like qualifications and preferences).
Lets say Task 1 takes place on week 31 only mornings and requires skills A and B. Task 2 takes place on week 32 only afternoons and requires skills B and C.
Then I have resource 1 who is available only mornings and selected weeks and has skills A, B and C. Resource 2 meanwhile is available whole day and has only skills B and C.
Now I'd need resource 1 to be automatically allocated to Task 1 and Resource 2 to Task 2. And of course I'd need to avoid situation where one resource gets allocated to two tasks in the same week.

Is this something that even is possible? I know I could use some advanced project management solutions but the team is already using Google Sheets and this is once a year scenario so acquiring entire separate solution is not so reasonable. If this was somehow not possible in Google Sheets but only in Excel, that would still be very useful.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. This question might be a better fit for [pm.se] if you make it more specific / less primarily opinion-based.